# Cannot find bounds of Current function

Tags: c, debugging, bounds

I'm implementing an insertion sort on a 16384 array on C.

The sorting algorithm is functioning properly but when the free(inser) command is encountered, the debugger is outputting the Cannot find bounds of current function error.

Can this be caused because I'm using a 32-bit mingw on a 64-bit machine?

```
int main(void) {
    int i,t,j;
    int *inser = malloc(sizeof(int)*16384);
    int *shell = malloc(sizeof(int)*16384);
    srand(time(NULL));

    for(i=0;i<=16384;i++){
        *(inser+i) = rand()% 17000;;
        *(shell+i) = *(inser+i);
    }


    for(i=1;i<=16384;i++){
        j = i-1;
        while((*(inser+i)<*(inser+j)) && (j >=0)){
            t = *(inser+i);
            *(inser+i) = *(inser+j);
            *(inser+j) = t;
            j--;
            i--;
        }
    }

    for(i=0;i<=16384;i++){
        printf("%d\t",*(inser+i));
    }

    free(inser);
    free(shell);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The memory you allocate can be used as an array, with array-like indexing (e.g. `inser[i]` instead of `*(inser+i)`). When you do that you might realize that your loops will step out of bounds.

Comment: `i<=16384` --> `i<16384`

Answer (score 1):

Apart from the loop bounds error, which has been pointed out by others, look at the line marked “WARNING”, below (I also cleaned up your code to make it more readable). On this line, when `j` starts off as zero, `j` becomes -1. This value will then be used here:

```
while( inser[i] < inser[j] && j >= 0 ) { ... }
```

The logical “and”, `&&`, is a shortcut operator: its left-hand side (LHS) is always evaluated, and the right-hand side is only evaluated if the LHS evaluates to “true”. So `inser[-1]` will always be evaluated after the last inner loop iteration because `j` has been decremented from 0 to -1 by `j--` before the final loop test where `j>=0` will fail, but not before `inser[j]` has been evaluated.

You could exchange the operands to `&&` to avoid this problem, getting this:

```
while( j>=0 && inser[i] < inser[j] ) { ... }
```

Other than that, I can't say if your (corrected) code will behave as intended.

Turn on all compiler warnings and you might catch a few errors.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

/* Avoid magic numbers */
#define ARRAY_SIZE   (16384)
#define RAND_CEILING (17000)

int main(void) {
    int i;          /* Indexing and iteration variable. */
    int j;          /* Indexing and iteration variable. */ 
    int t;          /* Temporary variable for swapping. */
    int *inser;     /* Sorted array.                    */
    int *shell;     /* Original array.                  */


    /* Always check the return value of malloc() */
    inser = malloc(ARRAY_SIZE*sizeof(*inser));
    if( inser == NULL ) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Call to malloc() failed for 'inser'.\n");
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    shell = malloc(ARRAY_SIZE*sizeof(*shell));
    if( shell == NULL ) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Call to malloc() failed for 'shell'.\n");
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }


    /* Seed the PRNG */
    srand(time(NULL));


    /* Correct the bounds on the iteration */
    for(i=0; i<ARRAY_SIZE; i++) {
        inser[i] = shell[i] = rand() % RAND_CEILING;
    }


    /* Sort 'inser' */
    for(i=1; i<ARRAY_SIZE; i++) {
        j = i-1;
        while( inser[i] < inser[j] && j >= 0 ) {
            t = inser[i];
            inser[i] = inser[j];
            inser[j] = t;
            j--;                       /* WARNING: 'j' becomes -1 here */
            i--;
        }
    }


    /* Dump 'inser' to stdout */
    for(i=0; i<ARRAY_SIZE; i++) {
        printf("%d\t", inser[i]);
    }


    /* Cleanup */
    free(inser);
    free(shell);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: +1 nice catch on the `j = -1`.  Could do `j = i; while( j-- > 0 && inser[i] < inser[j] ) { ... }` and use `size_t` for `i,j`, which makes more sense for as they are array indexes.

Answer (score 1):

**Make sure your debugger and compiler executable's paths are towards same MingW build**

A bit Explanation:

I encountered the same error. I have already installed MingW package on my windows. As you know CodeBlocks also come with MingW in some packages. So, I had two MingW in My Windows. However, I noticed the path for the compiler installation directory (in **Settings/Compiler/Toolchain Executables/**) was set to different one and the debugger (in **Settings/Debugger/Default** -> Executable Path) was set to different MingW version. I changed them to same build that I installed before CodeBlocks explicitly. Now, it is working fine. There may be many reasons for an erorr/bug. It worked for me and I hope it will also help someone else...

Answer (score 0):

Just allocate the buffers on the stack

```
int inser[16384];
int shell[16384];
```

The heap is evil son.

Comment: When I used array indexing with a size of 16384, the program started freezing a lot, even during debugging. That is why I decided to use the heap which eliminated the freeze.

Comment: your stack space is probably not big enough, go with the heap.

Comment: There's nothing evil about the heap. If he has 4-byte `int`s (probably true), that's 128KiB of stack, which he might not have (the default stack size in my shell is 8KiB). Using `malloc()` is the right call here.

Answer (score 0):

Change the 3 `for()` loop terminations.   As @Joachim Pileborg & @BLUEPIXY point out, the `for()` loops are executing once too often.

```
for (i = 0; i < 16384; i++) {
... 
for (i = 1; i < 16384; i++) {
...
for (i = 0; i < 16384; i++) {
```

Avoid naked magic numbers

```
#define ASIZE (16384)
int *inser = malloc(ASIZE * sizeof(int));
...
for (i = 0; i < ASIZE; i++) {
```

See  @Emmet answer for indexing of `-1` concern.

Comment: If he's to avoid naked magic numbers, he should avoid them in the `for`-loop bounds too.

Comment: @Emmet Agreed, that is why I used `ASIZE` in `for (i = 0; i < ASIZE; i++) {`.

Comment: Sorry, @chux, my mistake. I read the first stanza and thought you were recommending it because you'd corrected the loop bounds.

Answer (score 0):

Your first for loop is going to run 16385 times, since it will run once for every number between (inclusive) 0 and 16384. Since your array has 16384 elements you will be overrunning it. This is what Joachim and BLUEPIXY are getting at. [This bytes.com question](http://bytes.com/topic/c/answers/786078-error-cannot-find-function-bounds) explains why that causes the gdb error.